# Why goes my paragraph always behind my button?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Everytime I shrink the window, my text in the footer goes behinde my button:[image: Text behind Button]

How can I fix that?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div data-role="footer" class="footer2">
    <a href="#seiteHome" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn-back ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-hover-a ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-back">Home</a>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.footer2 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 7px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    clear: both;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `button` is likely to have `position` of either `absolute` or `fixed`. So it will be on top of everything, yes

Comment: @Alexander Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: have you tried '.footer2 p {clear:both;}' ?

Comment: @LGVentura Yes, see CSS code

Comment: i mean '.footer2 p', in your paragraph inside .footer2. you tried it only in '.footer2'

Comment: @LGVentura Oh, didn't see it, sorry! But it didn't work

Comment: is your page online?

Comment: @LGVentura Try not to promote the sharing of personal references. A [minimal, working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) can be [edited into the post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), provided any other relevant markup and CSS is included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the text to appear to the right of the button without overlap, add some padding on the left of the `<p>` element:

```
.footer2 p {
    padding-left: 84px;
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/4qoao252/)**

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
.footer2 {
   text-align: center;
   padding: 7px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   clear: both;
   margin-top: 30px;
}
```

or

```
.footer2 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 7px 7px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  clear: both;
}
```